# Cloud Firestore document add gives error "Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, postman

I'm working on a react project and this is my very first react project. This code is deployed successfully. But get some errors while testing with postman. I "post" the "createScream" functions's URL and send it. then I got this errors.

Any help towards resolution is highly appreciated. I'm new to react world. Here's my index.json file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
 exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello world");
 });

 exports.getScreams = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)=> {
     admin
     .firestore()
     .collection('screams')
     .get()
     .then(data=>{
         let screams =[];
         data.forEach(doc =>{
             screams.push(doc.data());
         });
         return res.json(screams);
     })
     .catch((err)=> console.error(err));
 });

 exports.createScream = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)=> {
    const newScream = {
        body:req.body.body,
        userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    };

    admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('screams')
    .add(newScream)
    .then((doc)=>{
        res.json({message:'document ${doc.id} created successfully'});
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).json({ error:'something went wrong'});
        console.error(err);

    });
```

I got this error message

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field body).
    at Object.validateUserInput (E:\survival\TF2\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\serializer.js: 273: 15)
    at Object.validateDocumentData (E:\survival\TF2\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\write-batch.js: 611: 22)
    at CollectionReference.add (E:\survival\TF2\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js: 1765: 23)
    at exports.createScream.functions.https.onRequest (E:\survival\TF2\functions\index.js: 38: 6)
    at Run (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js: 608: 20)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js: 582: 19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js: 7: 71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js: 3: 12)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: The error says that you are sending and `undefined` value. Can you paste what you are sending as body in you POST?

Comment: Just make sure to add Content-Type:application/json header when sending the request via postman

Comment: It's unclear how this is related to React if you're using Postman to make the request.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm following a react and firebase project using video tutorials. I'm just in the beginning

Comment: @OronBen-David my firebase.json file is totally empty.  Take a look at this                                 {
  "functions": {
  
  }
}                  previously I got "functions predeploy error" So I removed the content. before it was like this  {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"

    ]
  }
}

Comment: @ErandiDilshani it is not related to firebase.json :) . I talking about postman. you need to specify the Content-Type:application/json header https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/

Comment: @OronBen-David oh sorry! I have specified the content types. But it still doesn't work. When I click send firebase doesn't update

Comment: @JohnnyZabala                                                                                                        {
    "body": "New Scream 1",
    "userHandle": "user1"
}

Comment: @ErandiDilshani check Doug answer. I think it is the right one. I see that you are sending body in you the POST body, so you might need to debug the `req.body` to see what you are actually getting there.

Comment: thank you all for supporting me. My problem was with the URL and I fixed it. Thnx again :D

Answer (score 19):

The problem is with this code:

```
const newScream = {
    body:req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
};

admin
.firestore()
.collection('screams')
.add(newScream)
```

When you try to add a document to Cloud Firestore where one of the property values is `undefined`, you will get this error.  This means that at least one of the three properties on `newScream` is undefined.  The error message is telling you which one:

> Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value **(found in field body)**

So, the body property is undefined.  You'll need to debug your function and figure out why `req.body.body` is undefined.  Perhaps the client isn't passing that value.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. In my case i had an undefined id. I guess there is also a new way to ignore undefined values as the error message now says "If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`."  But where do one even enable this?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure when using postman to change to POST method, On the body section underneath the url, click on the raw option, and on the dropdown that most likely says Text, change it to JSON. [image]

Comment: For me I changed "raw" to "x-www-form-urlencoded" under the BODY tab and it worked.  Prior to that I was trying to POST from the Params section instead of the Body section.

Comment: JSON did the trick for me - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To solve this issue, use the `ignoreUndefinedProperties` **setting** on the Firestore instance.

This skips undefined properties during serialization so that they don't get written into the Firestore document in the first place:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
firestore.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
const doc = firestore.doc(`demo`);
doc.create({ id: 1, description: undefined }); // works without exception
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for my case was using **userHandle**, while in the users i had used **handle**. I just renamed the value in scream post from userHandle to just handle, see below:

**Before**

```
const newScream = {
  body: req.body.body,
  userHandle: req.user.userHandle,
  createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
};
```

**After Correction**

```
const newScream = {
  body: req.body.body,
  userHandle: req.user.handle,
  createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I also try to the same coding and I solved the problem.

In postman, you will see the error `Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field body).` but it's Ok. Because it doesn't have any data in your post URL.

You may be mistaken for the screen to see. Click the `body tag` under the URL input place. Then select `raw`. Finally switch to JSON and your problem will be solved.
Write the JSON data in the red line in the picture below.

And Then, after writing the JSON data and you press `[send]`, you will be able to see `message :~~ successfully` at the under screen.

Try it!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I sent the request from *postman* as **raw** data, changing the data type to **json** made it work!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same project that you worked. i got same error and just rewrite createdScream code, relaunch postman and create new POST request.
Then send new request. That works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well.

It turns out the mistake I made was that in

```
const newScream = {
    body:req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
};
```

The `userHandle` in `req.body.userHandle` has lowercase `user` while in postman json

```
{
  'body':'new',
  'UserHandle': 'new'
}
```

the request sending out has `UserHandle` uppercase.

I fixed the issue by changing `userHandle: req.body.userHandle` in js to uppercase 
`UserHandle: req.body.UserHandle`.

Make sure whatever in `const newScream` matches exactly what you are trying to send out in postman json.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found another alternative solution by selecting 'x-www-form-urlencoded' in Body of the method 'POST' in Postman. Modify the keys and values then send.

Answer (score 0):

[Postman Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVvxO.png)

So, I just did **firebase deploy**, instead of ***firebase serve*** and everything worked fine & I was able to add newScream.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are using the right endpoint in postman

for every firebase function there should be a unique endpoint

for example:
for `getScreams` function, you have a link

```
https://us-central1-chat-app-xmx.cloudfunctions.net/getScreams
```

for `createScreams` functions you will have another link, for example:

```
https://us-central1-chat-app-xmx.cloudfunctions.net/createScreams
```

Now the link you should use in postman for`post request` is `createScreams` endpoint and for `get request` you need to use `getScreams` endpoint

The error you get is not a big deal because the process need a client to enter some data, but you need to use the right endpoint to send your document successfully to firestore

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that JSON(application/json) is selected in Postman or what ever rest API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved the problem was fixing the value given to the `createdAt` property in post request. By giving values to both `_seconds` and `_nanoseconds`:

> "createdAt":{"_seconds":1623472200,"_nanoseconds":0},

instead of just giving time value

> "createdAt": "10:00pm",

Answer (score 0):

Undefined is not an acceptable value in Firestore. And the data you are setting needs to be an object `{}` not an array `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this here and after a quick test, it seems that `firebase` will accept `null`s but not `undefined`. I resolved it in my project by redefining my model class as `order: Order | null;` rather than `order?: Order;`